# Getting Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I have installed Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4.16 on Windows 8 with instantclient10_1, Oracle 11g
I have done following already

1. Setup instantclient10_1 in path variable
2. Enabled extension=php_oci8.dll in php.ini
3. Setup extension_dir = "C:\php\ext\"
4. Verified php_oci8.dll if it exists at C:\php\ext\ location

Still getting Call to undefined function oci_connect() error. Please help. Also Oci8 Support is not enabled in phpinfo.

Comment: Assuming you are running a website, did you restart the web server so it would reload PHP?

Comment: Yes restarted httpd and also system several times

Comment: 5.4 was end-of-lifed almost two years ago...

Comment: Are you using the right DLL for the version of PHP.  If you've used the thread-save DLL for the non-threadsafe version of PHP, it's not going to load.

Comment: @Alex Howansky, due to some unavoidable condition i am using 5.4

Comment: Heh heh the much-feared L-word: LEGACY. :)

Comment: DLL came with thread save PHP package i downloaded.

Comment: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) they say: _With **Oracle 12c** libraries use `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` or `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` or `extension=php_oci8.dll`. **Only one** of these DLLs may be enabled at a time_ - So maybe you enabled more then one extension?

Comment: @Alon Eitan - i have enabled only extension=php_oci8.dll , ;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll is commented

Comment: do a phpinfo() to find out the correct php.ini,sometimes there are more than one

Comment: @Mihai i have checked this too. Its the correct one. Also i have checked extension directory path, its correct.

Comment: You said you had instantclient10_1 .  You need Instant Client 11.2 or 12.1 or 12.2